# Accented chars are not retrieved correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I encountered this strange issue today. We have an email field in our page, and if a user enters:
specialcharacter123@eñe.es

Then only in case of Chrome I am getting `specialcharacter123@xn--ee-zja.es` :

I tried:

```
jQuery('#email').val()
```

And

```
document.getElementById('email').value
```

Both gave me same results. ( It is working fine in Safari ).

Also I already have this in the page:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

I am unable to get any clue what's wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

According to w3.org about input type=email – e-mail address input control:

> Value: Any string that matches the following [ABNF] production:
>
> 1*( atext / "." ) "@" ldh-str 1*( "." ldh-str )
>
> …where atext is as defined in [RFC 5322], and ldh-str is as defined in
> [RFC 1034].
>
> That is, any string which matches the following regular expression:
>
> /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/

Source: https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120329/input.email.html

As you can see from the regular expression above, the value entered must not contain non-ascii characters. This is problematic because email addresses do sometimes contain non-ascii. All Chrome has done is (stupidly) punycode encode the domain part of the email address so that it can meet the requirements of the w3c. What they should have done is left it alone since it goes without saying that form validation should either accept the user's input or reject it, but never change it.

Answer (score 1):

Domain names can include ASCII characters only, see [Internationalized domain name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name). The URL will work just fine when doing requests, but if you want to display it as UTF8, you need to convert it. There are various solutions for various languages, for JavaScript you could use [punycode.js](https://github.com/bestiejs/punycode.js).

Answer (score 0):

This is really strange; But I have fixed this issue by doing following changes:

**FROM:**

```
<input type="email" id="email" ></input>
```

**TO:**

```
<input type="text" id="email" ></input>
```

Type is changed from `email` to `text` and now it is working fine. ( *This solution have other issues but I can live with that* ). In Chrome `type='email'` is not working as expected. Accented chars are getting converted to punycode.