# Input type email value in Chrome with accented characters wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

When entering accented characters into an input type email in Chrome, it changes the value to something strange.

When entering the email: *test@Bücher.ch* the input value becomes: *test@xn--bcher-kva.ch*.

```
$('#email').val() // --> test@xn--bcher-kva.ch
document.getElementById('email').value // --> test@xn--bcher-kva.ch
```

This does not happen with an input type text, or in other major browsers.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ChrisFraser/dsmcsdxg/) for example. What is going on here and how do I get around it?

Comment: Same problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24818970/accented-chars-are-not-retrieved-correctly If you need email type, maybe second answer could help...

Comment: Looks like Chrome doesn't support IDN for TLDs and is converting them to [Punycode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode)

Comment: Both addresses are identical, you should be able to use either.

Comment: The punnycode version does not read so nicely and confuses users.

Comment: I add an email like this gmaiĺ.com the problem is the html validation and most server validations will pass. If have to check the DNS MX records.

Comment: I found a solution that uses type="text" to get around form validation errors while still keeping the @ symbol on mobile keyboards (tested in Chrome for Android) and packaged it as a drop-in .js file. My email is in my profile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it's not an error, it's because of the specification. Chrome just follows the specification in a different way than other browsers:) and translate the IDN into its ascii representation.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=410937

To decode it back you can use some 3rd party solution such as

[Converting punycode with dash character to Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183485/can-anyone-recommend-a-good-free-javascript-for-punycode-to-unicode-conversion)

Answer (score 2):

For others who face this problem again, I suggest use `punycode` npm package.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/punycode

I think only Chrome encodes email into punycode. There is no way to prevent Chrome from punycoding. You just let her do her work and decode punycode in backend.

```
const punycode = require('punycode')
let data = request.only(['email'])
data['email'] = punycode.toUnicode(data['email'])
```

Worked like charm in adonis and my headache disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

On my side I have just changed the type of the input field from email to text and now it's working fine.

It was

```
<input id="Email" name="Email" type="email">
```

And now it is

```
<input id="Email" name="Email" type="text">
```

Answer (score -1):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/erenyener/dsmcsdxg/3/)

```
<form>
    <input id="email2" type="text"placeholder="your@email.com" autofocus required pattern="[^ @]*@[^ @]*">
    <input type ="submit">
</form>
```

For this problem it is because of input's email type, after '@' sign browser gives this error. I think they believe email adresses always must be in English.

Anyway Use text type then provide email regex

Comment: See Lukas Kral's answer for why this is not an error