# Prevent Angular from mangling email inputs

Tags: angularjs, unicode, domain-name

If I have an `<input type="email">`, and the user enters an [Internationalized Domain Name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name), Angular *(EDIT: except it's not Angular's fault - see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37205099/1469259) for details)* automatically converts the value to [punycode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode), which is a nice feature, but very confusing for users if the value is displayed back to them. E.g.

```
abc@ábc.com
```

becomes

```
abc@xn--bc-lia.com
```

It also causes issues when a backend is expecting the original Unicode version of the domain, and the Angular app instead sends the punycode version.

I can use e.g. [punycode.js](https://github.com/bestiejs/punycode.js/) to convert it back, but is there a way to do this in Angular without involving another library - either tell Angular not to do the encoding, or get the original value subsequently?

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function thing($scope) {
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<p>Copy this text into the input:</p>
<p>abc@ábc.com</p>
<div ng-controller="thing">
  <input id="inp" type="email" class="form-control" ng-model="addr">
  <p>Model gets: {{addr}}</p>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I think the question (and the answer) could be easier to find on the internet if it would be: "Prevent Chrome email input forms from converting to Punycode"

Comment: True, but at that point, does it become basically a dupe of the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37205099/1469259) I linked in my answer? If I google `chrome email punycode`, that question comes up straight away. Your answer below is a good point though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out it's not Angular that's doing it, it's Chrome (Safari does *not* have the same behaviour, haven't tested other browsers). See for example [Input type email value in Chrome with accented characters wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32117497/input-type-email-value-in-chrome-with-accented-characters-wrong)

Here's an example of it happening without Angular - try this in Chrome:

```js
function update() {
  document.getElementById('output').innerText = document.getElementById('inp').value
}
```

```html
<p>Copy this text into the input:</p>
<p>abc@ábc.com</p>
<div ng-controller="thing">
  <input id="inp" type="email" onchange="update()">
  <p>Browser says: <span id="output"></span></p>
</div>
```

So the short answer is no, there's no way of stopping this via Angular - and currently there doesn't appear to be a way to tell Chrome not to do it either.

Answer (score 1):

As for today: 2021-05-06 these are the browsers behaviors regarding converting **input fields from `type=email`** on keystroke to Punycode:

- Chrome: Converts to Punycode
- Firefox: Does not convert to Punycode
- Safari: Does not convert to Punycode
- Edge: Does not convert to Punycode
- Internet Explorer: Does not convert to Punycode

**If you do not want this behavior on Chrome remove `type=email` from your input field!**

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you use `ng-model` on input type `email`, angularjs will use its magic on the input.

Try it without ng-model

Comment: But I want to bind the input to my model - without `ng-model` how would I achieve this?

Comment: You could use ng-change, to then bind to a scope variable, but read some docs. There must be a way to use ng-model while preventing angularjs to woe its magic on the input email

Comment: FYI, in case you're interested, turns out it's not Angular's fault - posted an answer to that effect