# How can I read the original value of an input field with type email without the Umlaut conversion?

Tags: javascript, html, email-address

I have a html input element on my page in which the user can enter his e-mail address:

```
<input type="email" id="yourEmail" name="yourEmail">
```

I do not send this field via the form directly but read it into a variable with javascript like this:

```
let email = document.getElementById('yourEmail').value.trim();
```

Now that works fine for *normal* e-mails, but as soon as I have special chars like German Umlauts, I get the transcribed email in the javascript variable. If I enter `mail@gründlicher.de` for example, the js variable contains the value `mail@xn--grndlicher-beb.de`. Since I want to show this data on a summary page back to the user before I sent it, that is really confusing to the user - it feels like something is broke (at least if you are not a techn nerd, understanding what happens).

Now I'm wondering: How do I get the text, that was actually entered by the user instead of the transcribed email? Obviously I could change form `type="email"` to `type="text"`, but then I will also loose the e-mail specific keyboard on mobile devices, which I would like to have.

Comment: Have you looked at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183485/converting-punycode-with-dash-character-to-unicode ?

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32117497/input-type-email-value-in-chrome-with-accented-characters-wrong

Comment: This conversion seems to happen for Chrome and Edge but not Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `type="text"` to get the special characters to display, then use `inputmode="email"` to allow for e-mail-specific keyboard on mobile devices:

```js
document.getElementById('yourEmail').addEventListener('change', function() {
  console.log(this.value);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" inputmode="email" id="yourEmail" name="yourEmail">
```